# Configuring MODx Revolution to work with both http and https

Tags: https, modx, modx-revolution

I have a website using MODx Revolution (2.2.10-pl, advanced install), let's call it `www.example.com`, which I want to be accessible with both http and https.

to achieve this, I tweaked the `site_url` context setting to be `[[++url_scheme]]www.example.com/`. Links created using `[[~id]]` seem to be alright, however, sometimes, the generated links are really weird. My interpretation is that the code to create links programmatically doesn't work with my settings, but I don't know why, or how else I would go about enabling both http and https.

**Question first, examples below:** How should I set the `site_url` or any other site/context setting so that links on my site work with both http and https? Optionally, is the behavior I see a bug, or expected behavior given Revolution's tag evaluation semantics?

---

**Misbehavior examples:**

When I click on "View" in the manager for a resource with the alias `example`, the address that is opened is

```
https://www.example.com/xyz/[[++url_scheme]]www.example.com/example/
```

where `xyz` is my manager URL. The expected URL is of course

```
https://www.example.com/example/
```

---

Another case where this happens is for failed logins; my login call looks like this (minus irrelevant parts):

```
[[!Login? &redirectToOnFailedAuth=`[[++unauthorized_page]]`]]
```

The `unauthorized_page`'s expected full URL is

```
https://www.example.com/special/401
```

but the URL which is opened for a failed login as `username` is

```
https://www.example.com/[[++url_scheme]]www.example.com/[[++url_scheme]]www.example.com/special/401?u=username
```

The second example is the same for http, except for the scheme, of course; I haven't logged into the manager with http.

---

**EDIT**

`.htaccess` at the webroot:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# redirect all requests to /en/favicon.ico to /favicon.ico
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(en)/favicon.ico$ favicon.ico [L,QSA]
#RewriteRule ^(en|nl|de)/favicon.ico$ favicon.ico [L,QSA]

# redirect all requests to /en/assets* /assets*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(en)/assets(.*)$ assets$2 [L,QSA]
#RewriteRule ^(en|nl|de)/assets(.*)$ assets$2 [L,QSA]

# redirect all other requests to /en/*
# to index.php and set the cultureKey parameter
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(en)?/?(.*)$ index.php?cultureKey=$1&q=$2 [L,QSA]
#RewriteRule ^(en|nl|de)?/?(.*)$ index.php?cultureKey=$1&q=$2 [L,QSA]
```

`.htaccess` in the manager's directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/xyz/$1
```

Comment: What about the htacess file at the MODx root? Is rewriting on/off there...under what conditions? Also could be the htacess in the manager root for MODx possibly. Just trying to think of issues I've run into like this in the past.

Comment: good point about htaccess, I added the non-comment parts for the root and manager directory. It seems that the part about FURLs is not enabled in the first htaccess, although we use it (successfully)... I'll try to find out what's going on there...

Comment: what is your base href tag? Can you try this <base href="[[!++site_url]]" />? Actually just this without any htaccess or context tweaks.

Comment: @orbitory yeah, very true. Forgot about that one in the templates.

Comment: ah yeah, I forgot the base href! It is `<base href="[[++site_url]]" />`, i.e. with caching. However, I think I have found the cause for this behavior (see answer), so I won't try to reproduce the issue in a clean install. If you have suggestions on my answer, I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with `$modx->makeUrl()`. For example, for the

```
[[!Login? &redirectToOnFailedAuth=`[[++unauthorized_page]]`]]
```

call, in `core/components/login/controllers/web/Login.php`:

```
public function checkForRedirectOnFailedAuth(modProcessorResponse $response) {
    $redirectToOnFailedAuth = $this->getProperty('redirectToOnFailedAuth',false,'isset');
    if ($redirectToOnFailedAuth && $redirectToOnFailedAuth != $this->modx->resource->get('id')) {
        $p = array(
            'u' => $this->dictionary->get('username'),
        );
        $message = $response->getMessage();
        if (!empty($message)) $params['m'] = $message;
        $url = $this->modx->makeUrl($redirectToOnFailedAuth,'',$p,'full');
        $this->modx->sendRedirect($url);
    }
}
```

the last two lines do a redirect to a URL generated with `makeUrl`, which will be something like `[[++url_scheme]]www.example.com/etc` (**note:** I'm not 100% sure here, as I can't easily look at the raw URL. The conclusions still hold, though). If the URL is simply shown on the page, this is no problem, because MODx will parse the tag before inserting it into the html output. However, as the URL is used directly for the redirect, no such replacement takes place, and the browser interprets it as a relative URL, resulting in target URLs such as `https://www.example.com/[[++url_scheme]]www.example.com/etc`.

So much for the problem. To avoid this, `site_url` must be a literal value without any tags in it. As a workaround, I now use the following snippet as the first thing in my template:

```
$modx->config['site_url'] = $modx->config['url_scheme'] . substr($modx->config['site_url'], strlen('[[++url_scheme]]'));
return '';
```

together with a `[[++site_url]]` of

```
[[++url_scheme]]www.example.com/
```

Note that some parts of MODx don't seem to notice this update, which is why it's important to still use `[[++url_scheme]]` in your `site_url`. As far as I can tell right now, the parts that don't see the update, stuff like `[[~id]]`, work properly with `url_scheme`.

**EDIT** this does of course only fix the "View" buttons in the manager if you tweak the manager templates accordingly.

**WARNING** this is of course very hacky, and not yet tested very well. The fact that some features do not see the overwritten value means that you're introducing an inconsistency into your website, which may lead to subtle errors! If a more clean solution comes up, go for it!

Comment: try removing the full from $url = $this->modx->makeUrl($redirectToOnFailedAuth,'',$p,'full'); Should just output a url without the domain. That might fix some of your issues.